# How to bind .change() event in jquery to a dynamically generated html element

Tags: php, html, jquery-ui, jquery

```
$("#mySelect").val(subgroup_id).change()
```

here `mySelect` is a drop down generated dynamically

Comment: var subgroup_id = $("#subgroup_id").val();

its a value of a textbox

Comment: Sorry i cant find the solution for my problem. I tried using on and load, but cant get it right

Comment: You may to provide a little more code in order to get an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You'd do that by using the delegated version of `on()`, and delegate the event to the closest non-dynamic parent (using the document in the example below) :

```
$(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function() {
    this.value = subgroup_id; //sets the value on change ????
});
```

Comment: I want to call change event with the value subgroup_id.. I dont want to do any stuffs

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that, but are you trying to set the value on a change event ???

Comment: yes. I am trying to set a value and call change event. The change event triggers the AJAX.

Comment: Then the code you're using should work just fine, there are no special tricks for that, but the element has to exist when you're doing it, does'nt matter if it's dynamic or not, but you can't set the value or call a method on an element some time in the future so you have to this when the element is already insterted into the DOM.

Comment: `$(window).load(function() {
            

              $("#mySelect").val(subgroup_id).change();


  });`

I tried this but still not working

Answer (score 2):

Use the on() method - http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('body').on('change', '#mySelect', function() {
    // do stuff here
})
```

Comment: thanks for your response, there is no stuff to do, I want to call a change event for a dynamically generated element.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the change event?

Comment: change event calls an AJAX function

Comment: Then you would run the AJAX function where // do stuff here occurs. Or am I missing something?

Comment: i want to trigger the change event when this elemnt is loaded. Change the element with the value subgroup_id

Comment: When what element is loaded? I feel like you haven't explained everything that you need to occur.

Comment: I mean when all the element is loaded that is the page is loaded fully, because that "#mySelect" is not present in the current context, its generated dynamically

Comment: Generated dynamically by AJAX?

Comment: Then what we have shown you will work. The change event gets bound to the select box properly.